# Convincing business owner to upgrade from paper based to Java Application

Tags: helping

How do I convince/explain to a business manager to upgrade from their paper based log system, which causes over booking. Also, sometimes the customer's hand writing is not understandable, which causes issues for completion of work and report maintenance.

Overall, how do I convince them with respect to the principles, characteristics and features of programming in java.

I'm not looking for anything lengthy, just small stuff that I can say and build on.

Comment: Selecting the technology set and/or the programming language should not be your first step. The first step should be to convince them they need a better system, followed by a study of options of what those systems could be (which might include better paper systems), if a bespoke computer solution is eventually selected then the technology, architecture and infrastructure will probably be selected next, then the business, functional, non-functional and technical requirements coming next. THEN you can select your tools and language... Good luck!

Comment: Make a **business** case for whatever you are proposing. The language or whatever technology has sfa to do with the business case.

Comment: After you have made the business case that the current system needs to be replaced, you may find that there is all ready a booking system that you can buy that will meet your needs.  Not every piece of software needs to be built from scratch.

Comment: Building on WindRaven's comment: there **are** quite a few COTS systems for booking appointments.  As a manager I doubt I'd approve a new project for building a custom one unless those really didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, as mentioned in the comments, do not lead with the technology you want to use.  If you want to move away from an existing system, regardless of what type of system it is, you have to justify its cost.  The best way to do this, is to start with a cost/benefit analysis.

Gather information about how much time is spent using the current system, as well as a strong estimate of how much less time will be spent if the system is changed.  You may not know the salaries of the people using it, but your boss will, and he/she can use the hours to come up with a cost associated to the time spent.

It is possible that time is not an issue, in which case try to attach a cost to the overbooking, and legibility issues that are side effects of the current system.

Once you have a dollar amount tied to the current system, figure out what a replacement system would cost for the same activities.  If the savings is enough to justify investing in a new system, then you can start suggesting technologies to use.